# Header Redirect Conflict Confusion

Tags: php, redirect

I have read about 25 pages about this issue but no real clarity. More confusion than anything.

I have a redirect function I use below

```
function RedirectToURL($url){
   return header("Location: {$url}");
   exit();
}
```

then in my code when I want to redirect.

```
if (register($email, $username, $password)) {

    set_message('<div class="alert-success" data-closable>
    Account Registered.</div>');

    RedirectToURL("index.php");

}
```

Now it registers the user but produces the following error,

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent

I have no white spaces or anything.. I read that redirects cause this issue.

My dilemma is that the posts i have read say using ob_start is a good idea, but i found some posts also that say ob_start is a bad idea. because ob_start will remove the error but the issue will still exist.

So by those post i am confused and not sure the correct way to resolve this.

Comment: You're outputting something via the `set_message()`-function. Hence you have output before calling the `RedirectToUrl()`-function. ANY output, regardless of which file it is in, will do this. `ob_start()` is a perfectly okay way to fix the issue - it allows for headers to be issued after output, and will work just fine for the problem at hand.

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie do I have to call this after my session_start or can i add it to the code directly?

Comment: `ob_start()`  can be done either before or after `start_session()`- it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your function `set_message()` outputs passed parameter, headers already sent. You should not print anything before redirect. If you want to print some message after redirect, you can store it in `$_SESSION` on some key before redirect and output on the index page if the key exists.

Also, your `exit()` is unreachable. Remove `return` before `header()`.

```
function RedirectToURL($url)
{
   header("Location: {$url}");
   exit();
}

if (register($email, $username, $password)) {
    set_message('<div class="alert-success" data-closable>Account Registered.</div>');

    RedirectToURL("index.php");
}

function set_message($message)
{
    $_SESSION['redirect_message'] = $message;
}
```

Some block on your index page:

```
if (array_key_exists('redirect_message', $_SESSION)) {
    echo $_SESSION['redirect_message'];
    unset($_SESSION['redirect_message']);
}
```